# Information duplicating to new page in JQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have the following code in a separate file (called contact.html).

```
<div data-role="page" id="contact-us">
/* HTML for form */
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#contact-us", function () {

    $("#contact-btn").on("click", function() {
    var $form_details = $(this).parent("form").serialize();
    $form_id = $("#contact-type").val();
    $(".inner-content").html('<img src="img/loader.gif" class="video-loader">');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://app-url.co.za/app/includes/contact.php',
        data:{form_id: $form_id, form_details: $form_details},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $(".inner-content").html(data);
        }
    });
    });

    });
</script>
</div>
```

The data returned from my PHP file is:

```
echo "<div class='centered'><h2>Message sent successfully</h2><a href='landing.html' data-transition='slide' data-direction='reverse' class='line-btn' id='register' data-role='button'>Back to menu</a></div>";
```

So this all works - I get my success message and the "Back to menu" button. When I click this button it goes to landing.html, but the success message remains there instead of what's in my landing.html file.

This does not happen locally, only when I test this on an Android device (via PhoneGap build). Is this a misunderstanding I have about JQuery Mobile or an Android issue?

Any ideas?

Comment: thats the problem of jquery mobile... this kind of issues arises when you are using JQM...So try to avoid this library... but for now you can add data-ajax="false" in anchor tag like <a href='landing.html' data-ajax="false" data-transition='slide' data-direction='reverse' class='line-btn' id='register' data-role='button'> and check what happens...

Comment: try doing $(".inner-content").empty(); when forwarding to landing.html

Comment: Hi @Banik - thanks, unfortunately JQM is all I know at this point. This didn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @Rahul - where would I call this? Do I just add this to an onClick event?